# How to use Custom authorization providers with Supabse

Tags: javascript, supabase, supabase-database

I use the Supabase database and I want to do authorization using a third-party service that is not in the list of supported, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your query! Feel free to submit a Provider request on the [Supabase Auth thread](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/issues/451)

We also support self hosting, so it's possible to fork and add the provider on your own copy of Supabase Auth - feel free to take a look at [the PR adding Keycloak Auth](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/pull/371) for reference.

Hope this helps and let me know if there are further questions.

Jo